# gcloud filter using nested resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to check if a VPC Peering exists by filtering the gcloud output for the name of the peering, but can't quite get the gcloud command to work with my filter.... what I am trying to do is this:

`gcloud compute networks peerings list --project=<project> --flatten="peerings" --filter="peerings.name:<the_peering_I_want_to_check_for>"`
or
`gcloud compute networks peerings list --project=<project> --flatten="peerings[].name" --filter="peerings.name:<the_peering_I_want_to_check_for>"`

but both these returns the error:
`Invalid value for field 'filter' ..... Invalid list filter expression`

Have been following the suggestion on [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) - ***Filter on a custom list in response*** which talks about filtering for nested resources

This is an example of the output, that I want to retrive the ***peerings.name*** from

`gcloud compute networks peerings list --project=<project> --format="flattened(peerings)"`

```
---
peerings[0].importCustomRoutes:             False
peerings[0].name:                           the_peering_I_want_to_check_for
peerings[1].importCustomRoutes:             False
peerings[1].name:                           Antother_peering_that_i_don't_care_about_but_not_in_a_mean_way
```

Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe you can use `gcloud --format=json` with `jq`

Comment: @mbha-phoenix suggestion is good. `--format=JSON` and then using `jq`  provides a general-purpose way of formatting and filtering JSON

Comment: `gcloud` **generally** does provide sufficient functionality so that you need not use `jq` (see other comment) if you don't wish to do so. However, IMO, these `gcloud` commands are challenging. When you use `--flatten`, you're generally (!) going to want to provide the entire list, i.e. `--flatten=peerings[]` to flatten the lists elements. That *may* be all you need to change in your first example.

Comment: thanks very much guys for the comments.. I am able to do it through jq, or even just piping to grep, but was hoping to understand how to use the filter option of gcloud on it's own,, no matter what I use (even with `flatten=peerings[]` as suggested, it gives the same error:   

```ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.peerings.list) HTTPError 400: Invalid value for field 'filter': '[].peerings[].name eq 
 
".*\b<the_peering_I_want_to_check_for>\b.*"'. Invalid list filter expression.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the `gcloud` command, I try to run the following command in the cloud shell:

```
gcloud compute networks peerings list --project=YOURPROJECT --filter='name eq PEERING NETWORK NAME THAT YOU WANT TO CHECK' --format json --log-http
```

and `gcloud` returns an empty array, however we can see the command is sending the filter to the API and the API is returning the filtered list. It seems like the `gcloud` command is removing the results after the response from the API.

If I use the API in this [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks/list?apix&apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22your-project%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22name%3DVPC-NAME%22%7D) I get a value in the array of the response, regardless if I use `eq` or `=` in the request. [I created a public issue on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/195528410) so they can fix this issue.

Comment: Better late than never to say thank you! :-)